# Mocking animation completion callback in jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, react-transition-group

I'm trying to write a unit test with `Jest` for a `React`component that utilises `Transition` from `react-transition-group`. I need to mock the `Transition` so my tests don't have to wait for the animation to complete. However, in addition to 'skipping' the animation, I need the `onExited` callback to fire on my mocked `Transition` component.

Here's how my `Component.js` is using `Transition`:

```
...
return (
  <Transition
    timeout={1500}
    in={this.state.show}
    onExited={handleExited}>
    {status =>
      <button onClick={this.setState({show: false}) className={`component-${status}`}>button</button>
    }
  </Transition>
)
```

And here's my `Component.test.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {render, fireEvent} from 'react-testing-library'

import Component from '../Component'

test('check', () => {
  const handleCompletion = jest.fn()
  const {getByText} = render(
    <Component
      onButtonClick={handleCompletion}
    />
  )
  const button = getByText('button')
  fireEvent.click(button)
  expect(handleCompletion).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

The idea is that once a `button` is clicked, the component animates and then, on completion, fires a callback.

How do I mock the `Transition` correctly so it skips the animation but still fires the `onExited` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock modules with `jest.mock` like so:

```
jest.mock('react-transition-group', () => ({
    Transition: (props) => {
        props.onExited() // you can call it asynchronously too, if you wrap it in a timeout
        return <div>
            {props.in ? props.children() : null}
        </div>
    }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The `props.onExited()`, however, never gets called... I put a `console.log()` in my `handleExited` method in `Component.js`, but the message never gets logged. I have also checked if the `setState` is getting called when I click on the `button`, and it does. Any idea where it's failing? I inserted your code just before `const {getByText} = render(...` in my `Component.jest.js`.

Comment: My code needs to go after imports but before `test('check'...`

Comment: If I move your code after imports, it breaks all my other tests :) The error says `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.` I have updated my code sample in the question - I forgot to include that the child of the `Transition` component is actually a function `{status => ...}`. How should I update your mock to make it work?

Comment: you need to call the `props.children`, I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you! I have it working now. Only in the end, I have changed the code to `Transition: props => { !props.in && props.onExited(); return props.children(); }` as I need to return `children` always, and `onExited()` needs to be executed only when `in` is false.

Comment: late to the party here! any way to bind the DOM node to the `onExited` call?